# How to safely fill Boosts's pointer containers?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, boost-ptr-container

The first example for [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#std-auto-ptr-u-overloads) adds a raw pointer to the structure:

```
class zoo
{
    boost::ptr_vector<animal> the_animals;
public:

    void add_animal( animal* a )
    {
        the_animals.push_back( a );
    }
};
```

But what if `push_back`, or any other member function that might trigger reallocation, throws an exception during the process? From my understanding, in that case, it would be up to the caller to manage the memory for the given object, but because the caller passes a raw pointer to a class whose purpose is to manage memory, it's most likely that the caller doesn't.

So, wouldn't one need to use some kind of unique smart pointer in the code example above to wrap the pointer before providing it to the container and to be absolutely sure that no memory leaks? The containers do provide an overload for such smart pointers, but they don't enforce their usage.

Or is the argument that the containers simply won't ever throw exceptions during any add operation and it always succeeds?

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<animal>>`?

Comment: @noobProgrammer I do, I just came across those containers the first time today and thought of the problem in my question... It looks to me the example is not optimal for a container whose purpose is to manage memory and prevent leaks easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concerns you have are very valid if you were using `std::vector<animal*>` instead of `boost::ptr_vector<animal>`. Boost.PointerContainer is designed to handle pointers to resources that need to be freed, so it absolves you from having to worry about such things.

The Boost documentation provides exception safety guarantees for the various member functions. `ptr_vector` inherits `push_back` from [`ptr_sequence_adaptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html), and that lists the behavior of `push_back` as

> ```
> void push_back( T* x );
> ```
>
> Requirements: `x != 0`
>     Effects: Inserts the pointer into container and takes ownership of it
>     Throws: `bad_pointer` if `x == 0`
>     **Exception safety: Strong guarantee**

The [strong guarantee](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety) means that if `push_back` throws, the state of the container is rolled back to what it was immediately prior to the call to `push_back` and no resource is leaked. Now, you could argue that that doesn't guarantee anything about the resource you were trying to add to the container, but it would be very bad form on the part of the implementation to allow that resource to leak, especially since the call to `push_back` is supposed to take ownership of the object being passed by the caller.

If we look at the [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/ptr_container/ptr_sequence_adapter.hpp) of `push_back`, it shows how `ptr_vector` guarantees that the resource you're trying to add is not leaked.

```
void push_back(value_type x)  // strong               
{
    this->enforce_null_policy(x, "Null pointer in 'push_back()'");

    auto_type ptr(x);           // notrow
    this->base().push_back(x);  // strong, commit
    ptr.release();                // nothrow
}
```

So an `auto_type` is first constructed prior to the actual `push_back` operation being attempted. A bit more digging around reveals that `auto_type` is an alias for [`static_move_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/ptr_container/detail/static_move_ptr.hpp), which is a smart pointer type that will, when necessary, free the resource it owns upon destruction.

Thus, in the example shown, the `animal *` you're trying to add will never be leaked, even if an exception is thrown.